# METAR report - parse to Java

Tags: java, android, parsing, text

How can I do a parse of Metar information in Java programming?
I'v searched in the Internet and ther's a lot of complex things, I want something more simple.
I don't know how to use Regex or something like that...

example of Metar Info :http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/stations/ABBN.TXT

> 2011/03/16 05:30 ABBN 160530Z 23004KT 9999 NSC 02/M05 Q1029
>   R14R/CLRD60 NOSIG RMK G/O QFE696

Note that Metar report can have variations:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/METAR

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, there's the code (it can be useful for somebody):

```
    for (int i=0; i<httpGet.length(); i++) {  

           char c = httpGet.charAt(i);

           if(c=='M' && Character.isDigit(httpGet.charAt(i+1)) && 
                   Character.isDigit(httpGet.charAt(i+2)) &&
                   httpGet.charAt(i+3)== '/' &&
                   Character.isDigit(httpGet.charAt(i+4))&&
                   Character.isDigit(httpGet.charAt(i+5))&&
                   httpGet.charAt(i+6)==' ' &&
                   Character.isLetter(httpGet.charAt(i+7))){

               temp="-"+httpGet.substring(i+1,i+3);
               dewP=httpGet.substring(i+4,i+6);
               break;
           }

           else if(c=='M' && Character.isDigit(httpGet.charAt(i+1)) && 
                   Character.isDigit(httpGet.charAt(i+2)) &&
                   httpGet.charAt(i+3)== '/' &&
                   httpGet.charAt(i+4)== 'M' &&
                   Character.isDigit(httpGet.charAt(i+5))&&
                   Character.isDigit(httpGet.charAt(i+6))&&
                   httpGet.charAt(i+7)==' ' &&
                   Character.isLetter(httpGet.charAt(i+8))){

               temp="-"+httpGet.substring(i+1,i+3);
               dewP="-"+httpGet.substring(i+5,i+7);
               break;
           }

           else if(Character.isDigit(httpGet.charAt(i)) && 
                   Character.isDigit(httpGet.charAt(i+1)) &&
                   httpGet.charAt(i+2)== '/' &&
                   httpGet.charAt(i+3)== 'M' &&
                   Character.isDigit(httpGet.charAt(i+4))&&
                   Character.isDigit(httpGet.charAt(i+5))&&
                   httpGet.charAt(i+6)==' ' &&
                   Character.isLetter(httpGet.charAt(i+7))){

               temp=httpGet.substring(i,i+2);
               dewP="-"+httpGet.substring(i+4,i+6);
               break;
           }
           else if(Character.isDigit(c) && Character.isDigit(httpGet.charAt(i+1))
                   && httpGet.charAt(i+2)=='/' &&
                   Character.isDigit(httpGet.charAt(i+3)) &&  
                   Character.isDigit(httpGet.charAt(i+4)) &&
                   httpGet.charAt(i+5)==' ' &&
                   Character.isLetter(httpGet.charAt(i+6))){

                temp=httpGet.substring(i,i+2);
                dewP=httpGet.substring(i+3,i+5);
                break;
           }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Regex is almost certainly what your gonna want, yes is daunting but you will use it over and over again. The RMK section is going to be the hardest, it's the most free form.  The only alternative is to go through character by character with a lot of if's or case statements.

Answer (score -2):

This looks promising, I googled java METAR parse :-)
http://jfall-javafx.googlecode.com/svn-history/r6/WeatherFX/src/com/feldt/metar/Metar.java

Comment: I saw this yesterday, but it is a very complex project. I need something more simple, like you said, an regex or navigate in the text looking for the params.. any idea?